Audio wiring situation
Need help with 06 sonata radio wiring harness. I need to match the wires up in the pics. Need help with 06 sonata radio wiring harness.




Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Here is a wiring diagram that I can't ensure is correct but it sure looks like it's close to what you need:
https://portal-diagnostov.com/es/2020/03/26/radio-hyundai-sonata-lx-2006-system-wiring-diagrams/

